# Vue - Update rendered elements from a v-for with :style that uses their values

Tags: arrays, typescript, vue.js, bind, v-for

Is it possible to use object props in a *v-for* to dynamically update the *:style* directive? I have an array of values that I want to use in this computed property:

Script

```
get dotStyle() {
        if (this.clickedCoordinates === null) return { display: 'none' }

        for (var item of this.entity.damages) {
            this.x.push(item.blueprintPositionX);
            this.y.push(item.blueprintPositionY);
        }

        console.log(this.x, "x");
        console.log(this.y, "y");

        return {
            top: `${this.y[0]}px`,
            left: `${this.x[0]}px`,
        }
    }
```

Template

```
<div class="image-mark" :style="dotStyle"  />
```

This currently updates the position of the element for the first item in the array, but is there a way which I can loop through the array and use a *v-for* to render each array with the x, y values?

Apologies if my question is unclear and any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Which array do you need to loop around? is it like `v-for="damage in entity.damages"`?

Comment: @Bassie Yeah as you've said since each damage will have a blueprintPositionX & blueprintPositionY